# Modifying .htaccess rule to reflect current domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site that's using .htaccess file with a rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

However, I am setting a second domain that will be used for development and testing and will be using the same rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain2.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But because the domain is hard-coded, is there a way to make the rule use current domain, whatever it is?

The same I'd like to be able to apply to error rewrites:

ErrorDocument 400 http://mydomain2.com

Comment: `!^(www.mydomain2|www.mydomain1).com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use that just for adding `www.`, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```